# Parse duplicate rows beforeSave afterSave

Tags: javascript, android, mongodb, parse-platform

I am new to parse sdk but here is the situation which I've been struggling with.
I'm using android client and some CloudCode function.

I have 2 classes Joins and Groups.

### **Joins( stores every join requests )**

userId - Pointer to _User class
numberOfPeople
groupId - Pointer to Groups

### **Groups( identifies a group )**

placeId - Pointer to Place class
dateOfVisit

The group is identified by the **placeId** and **dateOfVisit**(these would construct the primary key).

### For example:

> **placeId    dateOfVisit**
>   111111111   2015-06-13 16:00
>   111111111   2015-06-14 16:00

When a user wants to join with **placeId:1111111111** and **dateOfVisit:2015-06-14 16:00** I want to check if there is an existing group or I need to create a new group and assign this groupId to this join request.

I have read the parse documentation and it is not possible to make unique rows in Groups because the lack of transaction/system locks, however there are some workarounds for it.

### Solution1: beforeSave + afterSave

would be to create a beforeSave and an aftersave hook JS method on Groups.
***BeforeSave*** would check
 - if there is already an existing group (with the placeId and dateOfVisit in the request) then do nothing
 - else save/create a new group.
***AfterSave*** would
 do a query.first equalTo( placeId and dateOfVisit in the request) with ascending order on the **createdAt** column and return this groupId and save this for the join request.

### Solution2: afterSave + background job

I don't care at all the duplicate entries
***AfterSave*** would
 do a query.first equalTo( placeId and dateOfVisit in the request) with ascending order on the **createdAt** column and return this groupId and save this for the join request.
***Background job*** would periodically delete all the duplicate entries except the min.**createdAt** entry.

Does these sound an overkill?
Any suggestions appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make `beforeSave` and `afterSave` at the same time, just `beforeSave` is enough.

In your Cloud Code, define a `beforeSave` function which:

- use `equalTo("placeId", placeId)` to `Groups` class to check if there is existing group.
- if the result returns null, you can create a new `Group` and assign the `userId` sent along with original request. Otherwise, associate the `userId` with the returned object.

Check more information about the Cloud Code [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries) and you might need to know about [Promises](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises) too

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
A group is identified by a placeId and a dateOfVisit. According to this, you basically suggest that using a beforeSave with a query equalTo(placeId) and equalTo(dateOfVisit) is enough to check an existing group?

Comment: Yes, if `dateOfVisit` were your group identifier

Comment: No, I want the group identifier to be the parse generated objectId.
So I don't want to create duplicate entries. or I misunderstood your comment...

Comment: Then you can use `equalTo("objectId",ID_OF_YOUR_GROUP)`